# Timeout error when downloading .html files from urls

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, urllib2, urllib

I get the following an error when downloading html pages from the urls.

```
Error: raise URLError(err) urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno
 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
 properly respond after a period of time or established connection
 failed because connected host has failed to respond>
```

Code:

```
import urllib2 
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

for i,site in enumerate(urls[index]):
    print (site)
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    page = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(req)
    page_content = page.read()
    with open(path_current+'/'+str(i)+'.html', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(page_content)
```

I think it may be due to some proxy settings or changing the timeout but I am not sure. Please help, I manually checked the urls seem to open perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you check the Proxy settings in your browser? If your company uses a proxy for surfing the internet, then specify it when using `urllib2`

Comment: @schlezzz15 Please elucidate more on this. Also, how do I know which browser it is using?

Comment: You said that you checked the URLs. I guessed you did that using the browser. If not, then how did you do that? **Note** setting the `User-Agent` inside the request header doesn't mean that the code opens or is executed within the browser.

Comment: @schlezzz15 Okay what exactly do you wish me to check? I am sorry if the question are naive, am new to using python.

Comment: in `urls[index]` you have a list of URLs. Can you check that they are available using the browser (e.g. Firefox)?

Comment: Yes, they are. I have checked that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78417/discussion-between-schlezzz15-and-abhishek-bhatia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since it doesn't happen to you most of the time, I can infer that your network is probably slow.
Try to set the timeout in the following way:

```
req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
timeout_in_sec = 360
page = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(req, timeout=timeout_in_sec)
page_content = page.read()
```

Comment: I get this error  `'Content-length', '%d' % len(data))
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia I don't know what `data` is, but from the error message I infer that you need to change that line to `'Content-length', '%d', data)`.