# Incorrect output when downloading .html files

Tags: python, urllib2

I simply wish to download .html files in python.
Code:

```
import urllib2 
    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    urls=['http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211']
    path='C:/Users/sony/Desktop/Python'
    for i,site in enumerate(urls):
        print (site)
        req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
        page = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor).open(req)
        page_content = page.read()
        with open(path+'/'+str(i)+'.html', 'w') as fid:
            fid.write(page_content)
```

But this gives this output sometimes
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B16PrXUjs69zWFJvWmJ6aFhyN0k/view?usp=sharing
which I don't get at all. 
I read this file using goose in python which shows nothing when I read such a file.

When it doesn't work:
http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211

Comment: @LutzHorn Please check now. Sry for not mentioning it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to do all the work for you using `.content` to let requests handle the encoding:

```
import requests

urls=['http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211']

 path='C:/Users/sony/Desktop/Python'

for i,site in enumerate(urls):
    print (site)
    req = requests.get(site)
    page_content = req.content
    with open ('{}{}.html'.format(path,i), 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(page_content)
```

Output:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> <!--NEW--> <!--- www pageHead.vm ---> <!--- mode=www ---> <!--- URI=/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211 ---> <!--- Host=www.nydailynews.com ---> <!--[if IE 8]><html class="ie8" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/"><![endif]--> <!--[if IE 9]><html class="ie9" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/"><![endif]--> <!--[if IE 10]><html class="ie10" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/"><![endif]--> <!--[if IE 11]><html class="ie11" lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/"><![endif]--> <!--[if !IE]><!--> <html lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/"> <!--<![endif]-->       <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>          <title>Fans stampede outside South African stadium - NY Daily News</title>     <meta name="nydn_section" content="Sports"/>   <meta name="viewport" content="width=1070, maximum-scale=1.0"/>  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="107464888913"/> <meta property="fb:admins" content="1594068001"/> <meta property="og:site_name" content="NY Daily News"/> <meta property="article:publisher" content="https://www.facebook.com/thenewyorkdailynews"/> <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="02916AAC0DA8B068EFE01D721E03ED7E"/>    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary"> <meta name="twitter:site" content="@nydailynews"> <meta property="twitter:url" content="http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211"/> <meta property="twitter:title" content="Fans stampede outside South African stadium"/> <meta property="twitter:description" content="Thousands of fans stampeded outside the stadium gates of a World Cup warmup game Sunday, five days before the start of soccer's showcase event. Several fans could be seen falling under the crush of people, many wearing Nigeria jerseys."/> <meta id="og_title" property="og:title" content="Fans stampede outside South African stadium"/> <meta property="og:type" content="article"/> <meta id="og_url" property="og:url" content="http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211"/>   <meta id="og_image" property="og:image" content="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.179213!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_1200/alg-stampede-johannesburg-jpg.jpg"/>   <meta id="og_description" property="og:description" content="Thousands of fans stampeded outside the stadium gates of a World Cup warmup game Sunday, five days before the start of soccer's showcase event. Several fans could be seen falling under the crush of people, many wearing Nigeria jerseys."/> <meta name="description" content="Thousands of fans stampeded outside the stadium gates of a World Cup warmup game Sunday, five days before the start of soccer's showcase event. Several fans could be seen falling under the crush of people, many wearing Nigeria jerseys."/>   <meta name="nydn_byline" content="MICHAEL LEWIS"/>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://assets.nydailynews.com/nydn/c/nydn.css?r=20120405mk1Bh">  <meta name="parsely-title" content="Fans stampede outside South African stadium"/> <meta name="parsely-link" content="http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211"/> <meta name="parsely-type" content="article"/> <meta name="parsely-image-url" content="http://assets.nydailynews.com/polopoly_fs/1.179213!/img/httpImage/image.jpg_gen/derivatives/landscape_1200/alg-stampede-johannesburg-jpg.jpg"/>    <meta name="parsely-pub-date" content="2010-06-06T15:01:04"/>   <meta name="parsely-section" content="Sports"/>   <meta name="parsely-author" content="Michael Lewis"/>       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://assets.nydailynews.com/nydn/c/article.css?r=20120405mk1Bh">       <meta name="robots" content="NOARCHIVE"/>         <link rel="canonical" href="http://www.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211">  <link rel="alternate" media="handheld" href="http://m.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211"> <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="http://m.nydailynews.com/sports/soccer-fans-stampede-south-african-stadium-nigeria-north-korea-world-cup-warmup-article-1.179211"/>     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/nydn/js/nydn-pack-20140101.js?r=20120405mk1Bh"></script>   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.nydailynews.com/nydn/js/article2014.js?r=20120405mk1Bh"></script>          <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->      


                              <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="NYDN Rss" href="http://feeds.nydailynews.com/nydnrss">              <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Sports Rss" href="http://feeds.feedburner.com/nydnrss/sports">       

..........................
```

If you want to try the same url a few times you can use a try/except catching the `requests.ConnectionError`:

```
def tries(path, url, i, max_tries=1):
    for ty in range(1, max_tries+1):
        try:
            req = requests.get(url)
            page_content = req.content
            with open('{}{}.html'.format(path, i), 'w') as fid:
                fid.write(page_content)
            break
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
            print("Error {} for try {}".format(e, ty))


for ind, url in enumerate(urls):
    tries(path, url, ind, 4)
```

Comment: Since work on slow internet connection I face some timeout issues http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30373301/timeout-error-when-downloading-html-files-from-urls . Do you think this will solve that as well? Or should I explictly specify a timeout in the above?

Comment: Cunninghan there is some error with your code `with open(path {}.html'.format(i), 'w') as fid:
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Yep. Missed an opening quote. Fixed. What do you want to happen if it times out?

Comment: Still there   `with open(path '{}.html'.format(i), 'w') as fid:
                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Running the above I get this`with open(path, '{}.html'.format(i), 'w') as fid:
TypeError: an integer is required`

Comment: Try it now.  Working from phone so hard to see properly

Comment: Thanks! Works now. What do you suggest about the time out issue?

Comment: It shouldn't time-out as I can access the sam url through browser. Thus, somehow increase the timeout period in requests.

Comment: Error `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='edition.cnn.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2012/11/01/world/europe/spain-halloween-stampede/index.html (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond)`

Comment: Do you want to keep trying if that happens?

Comment: Maybe, because it works fine sometimes and at times it doesn't. I don't understand why. Probably slow internet speed maybe an issue.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia, added a way to try a few times for each url.

Comment: Thanks! Still I get this though `Error HTTPConnectionPool(host='edition.cnn.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2010/WORLD/asiapcf/11/25/cambodia.festival.deaths/index.html (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) for try 1`

Comment: In `def tries(path, url, i, max_tries=1):` in actual I should change to `def tries(path, url, i, max_tries):` to allow it try more than once.

Comment: for url http://edition.cnn.com/2012/11/01/world/europe/spain-halloween-stampede/index.html I get this:
`Error HTTPConnectionPool(host='edition.cnn.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /2012/11/01/world/europe/spain-halloween-stampede/index.html (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) for try 1`

Comment: I have another outer loop to the one you specified it seems to break that as well. How to avoid that? Can you please specify

Comment: You need to wrap anywhere you are calling .get in an try

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the response header:

```
>> print page.info()
Cache-Control: public, max-age=300, s-maxage=300
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Server: fs3
Age: 103
Expires: Thu, 21 May 2015 13:36:40 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-encoding, Accept-Encoding
```

I see the content is gzipped, try to use [zlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zlib.html) module to decompress the data.

To check if the data is gzipped add the following line:

```
if page.info().get('Content-Encoding', '') == 'gzip':
    ... # decompress data
```

Please, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704754/convert-gzipped-data-fetched-by-urllib2-to-html) to have an example of how to decompress the body.

Comment: @schelzz15 What solution do you suggest?

Comment: @schelzz15 Two points- 1. Since I do this for many urls and this case is not present in all. Is there some possible way to check it 2. Can you provide a example please?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia I have added an URL to an example of how to do that.

Comment: Since all are not in gzip. I think there is should a check also. Can you specify how one can do that.

Comment: I don't think http servers are supposed to send gzip-encoded data unless the client lists that they support it (and I don't think urllib2 does out-of-the-box).

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo, that is a good point. Maybe someone set the server to transfer the response compressed regardless to the client request.